# To accelerate calculating of pi using TPL

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I need to calculate Pi - number via Monte-Carlo method using Task Parallel Library, but when my paralleled program is running, it calculates Pi - number much longer than it's unparallel analog.How two fix it? Paralleled calculating class and it's unparallel analog are below:

```
class CalcPiTPL
    {
        Object randLock = new object();
        int n;
        int N_0;
        double aPi;
        public StringBuilder Msg; // diagonstic message
        double x, y;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public void Init(int aN)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            n = aN; // save total calculate-iterations amount
            aPi = -1; // flag, if no any calculate-iteration has been completed
            Msg = new StringBuilder("No any calculate-iteration has been completed");
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            if (n < 1)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Inbalid N-value");
                return;
            }

            Random rnd = new Random(); // to create randomizer
            Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PointGenerator(n, rnd));
            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PointGenerator(n, rnd));
            tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PointGenerator(n, rnd));
            tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PointGenerator(n, rnd));
            Task.WaitAll(tasks[0], tasks[1], tasks[2], tasks[3]);

            aPi = 4.0 * ((double)N_0 / (double)n); // to calculate approximate Pi - value
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        public double Done()
        {
            if (aPi > 0)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Calculates has been completed successful");
                return aPi; // return gotten value
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // no result
            }
        }
        public void PointGenerator(int n, Random rnd)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n / 4; i++)
            {
                lock (randLock)
                {
                    x = rnd.NextDouble(); // to generate coordinates
                    y = rnd.NextDouble(); // 

                    if (((x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + (y - 0.5) * (y - 0.5)) < 0.25)
                    {
                        //Interlocked.Increment(ref N_0); 
                        N_0++; // coordinate in a circle! mark it by incrementing N_0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Unparallel analog:

```
class TCalcPi//unparallel calculating method
    {
        int N;
        int N_0;
        double aPi;
        public StringBuilder Msg; // diagnostic message
        double x, y;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public void Init(int aN)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            N = aN; // save total calculate-iterations amount
            aPi = -1; // flag, if no any calculate-iteration has been completed
            Msg = new StringBuilder("No any calculate-iteration has been completed");
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            if (N < 1)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Invalid N - value");
                return;
            }

            int i;
            Random rnd = new Random(); // to create randomizer
            for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            {
                x = rnd.NextDouble(); // to generate coordinates
                y = rnd.NextDouble(); // 
                if (((x -  0.5) * (x -  0.5) + (y -  0.5) * (y -  0.5)) <  0.25)
                {
                    N_0++; // coordinate in a circle! mark it by incrementing N_0
                }
            }
            aPi = 4.0 * ((double)N_0 / (double)N); // to calculate approximate Pi - value
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        public double Done()
        {
            if (aPi > 0)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Calculates has been completed successful");
                return aPi; // return gotten value
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // no result
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid `lock (randLock)`

Comment: If you have multi-processor system, multiple programs could be executed in parallel and you may be able to get answer in shorter time by using parallel library. In single processor system, multiple programs are executed one by one, so execution never be fasten and overhead for switching among programs makes execution slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written the `PointGenerator` in a way in which it can barely benefit from being executed in parallel.

- the `lock` means it will have basically single-threaded performance with additional threading overhead
- a global state `N_0` means you will have to synchronize access. Granted, since it's just an int you can use the `Interlocked` class for efficiently incrementing it.

What I would is to let each `PointGenerator` have a different `Random` object and a different counter. Then there won't be any shared mutable state which could cause problems. Be careful though, the default constructor of `Random` uses the tick count of the system. Creating several objects might result in random generators with the same seed.

Once all `PointGenerator` finish you combine the results.

This would be very similar to what some of the TPL overloads of [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) do.

Comment: What you can do to create multiple `Random`s at the same time is to create one based on time and then use values from that one as seeds for the other ones: `var primaryRandom = new Random(); var random1 = new Random(primaryRandom.Next()); var random2 = new Random(primaryRandom.Next()); …`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but it still shows up when searching for how to compute pi in parallel in C#. I have modified this to use the systems thread count for the workers. Also the lock is not needed if we use a return type for the workers, put some of the other variables in the worker function and finally let everything be put together by yet another task. This uses long for a larger count of iterations. The instances of `Random` are created with the thread id as the seed, which i hope makes them give different sequences of random numbers. Removed the Init-Method and put initialization in the Run-Method instead. There are two ways of using this now, blocking and non-blocking. But first here is the class:

```
public class CalcPiTPL
{
    private long n;
    private double pi;
    private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    private Task<int>[]? tasks = null;
    private Task? taskOrchestrator = null;
    private ManualResetEvent rst = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private bool isDone = false;
    public string elapsedTime = string.Empty;
    public double Pi { get { return pi; } }

    public void Run(long n)
    {
        if (n < 1 || taskOrchestrator!=null) return;

        isDone = false;
        rst.Reset();
        stopWatch.Start();
        this.n = n; // save total calculate-iterations amount
        pi = -1; // flag, if no any calculate-iteration has been completed

        tasks = new Task<int>[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PointGenerator(n));
        }

        taskOrchestrator = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Orchestrator());
    }

    private void Orchestrator()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        
        long N_0 = 0;
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            N_0 += task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        pi = 4.0 * ((double)N_0 / (double)n); // to calculate approximate Pi - value
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        tasks = null;
        taskOrchestrator = null;
        isDone = true;
        rst.Set();
    }

    public double Wait()
    {
        rst.WaitOne();
        return pi;
    }

    public bool IsDone()
    {
        return isDone;
    }

    private int PointGenerator(long n)
    {
        int N_0 = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n / Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
        {
            double x = rnd.NextDouble(); // to generate coordinates
            double y = rnd.NextDouble(); // 

            if (((x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + (y - 0.5) * (y - 0.5)) < 0.25)
            {
                N_0++;
            }
        }
        
        return N_0;
    }
}
```

Blocking call:

```
CalcPiTPL pi = new CalcPiTPL();
pi.Run(1000000000);
Console.WriteLine(pi.Wait());
```

non-blocking call:

```
CalcPiTPL pi = new CalcPiTPL();
pi.Run(100000000);
while (pi.IsDone()==false)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    // Do something else
}
Console.WriteLine(pi.Pi);
```

Adding an event would probably be nice, if someone wants to use this in a GUI application. Maybe i will do that later.
Feel free to correct, if i messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

When your whole parallel part is inside a lock scope nothing is actually parallel. Only a single thread can be inside a lock scope in any given moment.

You can simply use different `Random` instances instead of a single one.